# Get max and min keys from a collection with Underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

How can I get max and min keys from this kind of a collection with Underscore? Seems to be an easy task but I didn't find a quick solution.

```
{
    "2013-06-26":839,
    "2013-06-25":50,
    "2013-06-22":25,
    "2013-05-14":546,
    "2013-03-11":20
}
```

Comment: What kind of output do you want? An object doesn’t have any particular key ordering.

Comment: You're right. Then another question - how can I get min and max keys from this collection?

Comment: @SergeyBasharov: http://underscorejs.org/#max

Comment: @hamstu, how can I refer to the key from iterator there?

Comment: @SergeyBasharov: `var _max = _.max(obj, function(obj){ return obj; });`

Comment: I am not certain what you actually want? Do you want to compare the keys for max and min or the values and return the key names of the max and min?

Comment: My max and min results for this collection should be `2013-06-26` and `2013-03-11`.

Comment: Yes, but based on the keys or the property values? In your example both would return the same answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's little old question but there is a single line solution for the same, you can chain it.

```
var a ={
    "2013-06-26":839,
    "2013-06-25":50,
    "2013-03-08":25,
    "2013-05-14":546,
    "2013-03-11":20
};
_.chain(a).keys().sort().last().value(); //max: 2013-06-26
_.chain(a).keys().sort().first().value(); //min: 2013-03-08
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rahulchaturvedie/hv26eoz7/6/)

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, _.min and _.max only support numbers, so we can't use those for your string keys. Fortunately, your dates are in a string-sortable format.

```
var minkey, maxkey;
_.each(obj, function(value, key) {
   if (minkey == null || key < minkey) { minkey = key; }
});
_.each(obj, function(value, key) {
   if (maxkey == null || key > maxkey) { maxkey = key; }
});
```

Now, if you really wanted the **key** of the **max/min value**, then it's this. Luckily, your values are numbers, so that makes it a little easier:

```
var keys = _.keys(obj);
function itemgetter(key) { return obj[key]; }
minkey = _.min(keys, itemgetter);
maxkey = _.max(keys, itemgetter);
```

Comment: Your first example gives `Infinity` and `-Infinity`. I believe that `_.min` and `_.max` only handle numerical values. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/z4XSt/)

Comment: @Xotic750 hmm, never noticed that before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get the max and min key values of the object, if this is truly what you mean and not the key of max and min values (perhaps worth clarifying in your question), then for the example you have given, you could do it alternatively in POJS like this.

Javascript

```
function getMaxKey(object) {
    var max,
        i;

    for (i in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            if (!max) {
                max = i;
            } else if (i > max) {
                max = i;
            }
        }
    }

    return max;
}

function getMinKey(object) {
    var min,
        i;

    for (i in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            if (!min) {
                min = i;
            } else if (i < min) {
                min = i;
            }
        }
    }

    return min;
}

var test = {
    "2013-06-26": 839,
    "2013-06-25": 50,
    "2013-06-22": 25,
    "2013-05-14": 546,
    "2013-03-11": 20
};

console.log(getMaxKey(test));
console.log(getMinKey(test));
```

Output

```
2013-06-26
2013-03-11
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/V4gB5/)

Or using ECMA5 [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) as suggested by @dandavis

Javascript

```
function getMaxKey(object) {
    return Object.keys(object).sort()[0];
}

function getMinKey(object) {
    return Object.keys(object).sort().slice(-1)[0]
}

var test = {
    "2013-06-26": 839,
    "2013-06-25": 50,
    "2013-06-22": 25,
    "2013-05-14": 546,
    "2013-03-11": 20
};

console.log(getMaxKey(test));
console.log(getMinKey(test));
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/fejex/)

If on the other hand you want to get the key of the max an min values then you can do this in POJS.

Javascript

```
function getMaxKey(object) {
    var max,
        key,
        i;

    for (i in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            if (typeof max !== "number") {
                max = object[i];
                key = i;
            } else if (i > max) {
                max = object[i];
                key = i;
            }
        }
    }

    return key;
}

function getMinKey(object) {
    var min,
        key,
        i;

    for (i in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            if (typeof min !== "number") {
                min = object[i];
                key = i;
            } else if (object[i] < min) {
                min = object[i];
                key = i;
            }
        }
    }

    return key;
}

var test = {
    "2013-06-26": 839,
    "2013-06-25": 50,
    "2013-06-22": 25,
    "2013-05-14": 546,
    "2013-03-11": 20
};

console.log(getMaxKey(test));
console.log(getMinKey(test));
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/b9shz/)

In this case (with your specific test data) the output will be the same as the previous example.

Or using ECMA5 `Object.keys` and [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Javascript

```
function getMaxKey(object) {
    return Object.keys(object).reduce(function (previous, key) {
        return object[key] > object[previous] ? key : previous;
    });
}

function getMinKey(object) {
    return Object.keys(object).reduce(function (previous, key) {
        return object[key] < object[previous] ? key : previous;
    });
}

var test = {
    "2013-06-26": 839,
    "2013-06-25": 50,
    "2013-06-22": 25,
    "2013-05-14": 546,
    "2013-03-11": 20
};

console.log(getMaxKey(test));
console.log(getMinKey(test));
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/jceCM/)

This second example is easily accomplished by using the Underscore with some or all of these methods `_.keys`, `_.min` and `_.max` and has been answered already.

Comment: Object.keys(test).sort()[0] is shorter as is Object.keys(test).sort().slice(-1)[0] , while Math.max.apply(0, Object.keys(test)) works for numeric keys.

Comment: Indeed, these are possibilities when using ECMA5 [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) or a shim for it, as can be found on the MDN page.

Comment: @dandavis Added your ECMA5 suggestion for the first example and an ECMA5 solution for the other.